# How can I remove an element from a ng-repeat, but keep functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and struggling with something. I'm using a tinder-like library that lets you swipe images left or right. I also have a heart and "X" that will do the same thing.

What's happening is when you swipe left/right, the heart and "X" are being swiped too. I need these to remain stationary. I'm not sure how to do that and still have them render and function normally.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="ng-swippy noselect">
<div person="person" swipe-directive="swipe-directive" ng-repeat="person in peopleToShow" class="content-wrapper swipable-card">
  <div class="card">
      <div style="background: url({{person.thumbnail}}) no-repeat 50% 15%" class="photo-item"></div>
      <div class="know-label">{{labelOk ? labelOk : "YES"}}</div>
      <div class="dontknow-label">{{labelNegative ? labelNegative : "NO"}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container like-dislike">
    <div class="circle x" ng-click="$parent.$parent.clickDisike()"></div>
    <div class="icon-like" ng-click="$parent.$parent.clickLike()"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div><!-- end person-->
```

If I move the `like-dislike` container out of the `person` div, 2 things happen. That container does not render on screen and even if it does, it throws an error.

How can I keep them stationary and keep their functionality as it relates to the app/image they represent?

Thanks in advance.

****EDIT****
Link: http://430designs.com/xperience/black-label-app/deck.php

Comment: Can' t you do that with simple css tricks, just make `circle x` or `icon-like` class stationary (eg: position: absolute). So when you swipe, the `card` class is replaced, while the buttons remain. Do you have a codepen or something ?

Comment: You have to move them out of your ng-repeat if they should remain the same. however you can set the active card on swipe and then do like and dislike on that

Comment: Sorry @DennyHiu, I just added the link I'm working on

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban, I just added a link. If I move them outside of the (I just did, per your suggestion), my functions won't fire at all

Comment: That's because you are using $parent, when you move them out you need to remove that @lz430

Comment: no worries @lz430, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try using this css for like-dislike element and place it above the person div

.like-dislike {
      position : 'absolute',
      top : 10px;
      right : 10px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just removing the `$parent.$parent` from my ng-click.